# PHP extension is not loading when running fcgid

Tags: fastcgi, php, mod-fcgid

I need to use the `libpuzzle` extension for PHP, and so far I failed to make it run with `fcgid`. I have installed it (manually, unfortunately, because of the dependency issues) and added the `extension=libpuzzle.so` to my `/etc/php.ini`. Sadly, extension only gets loaded for PHP-cli, and doesn't get loaded for PHP running from `fcgid`. I tried:

1. Doing `service httpd restart` after installation and modifying `php.ini`, to no avail.
2. Checking `phpinfo()` to see if it's loaded or not, and it isn't with `fcgid`, but is with CLI. Extensions that were installed via `yum`, like `imagick`, are loaded fine.
3. Loading it during runtime with `dl()`, however, seems like ["this function has been removed from some SAPIs in PHP 5.3."](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php).

I'm at a loss. I don't want to get rid of FastCGI because of this single extension. I cannot install extension from the repo, because one of the dependencies (maybe PHP) is different version than expected from another repo (and I cannot downgrade that either because code relies on it). Please help.

I'm running CentOS 6 with PHP 5.4.17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `fcgid` was configured to use the `php.ini` file residing in the user directory instead of the one in `/etc`. Adding `extension=libpuzzle.so` to that configuration file has resolved the problem. So, if you're having a similar issue, that can be another thing to look out for.

Answer (score 2):

Given how many PHP related tasks are in progress on my server, I generally use a different php.ini file for Apache/mod_fcgid...

```
FcgidWrapper "/usr/bin/php-cgi -c /etc/httpd/conf/php.ini" .php
```

This way, all confusion as to what ini file has been parsed is removed.